# Using a closure in Swift

Tags: swift, closures

I am new to Swift, and just started the Swift Tour in an Xcode playground (which I think is great!). In the section "Functions and Closures" there is this simple function that, given an array of integers and predicate of type `Int -> Bool`, checks whether there is any integer in the array satisfying the predicate.

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: Int -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        if condition(item) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

So far so good. Now I wanted to use `hasAnyMatches` and an anonymous function ("closure") to write a second function `allMatch` that checks whether all integers in the array satisfy the predicate. This is what I tried:

```
func allMatch(list: [Int], p: Int -> Bool) -> Bool {
    return !(hasAnyMatches(list, condition : ({(n : Int) in return !(p(n))})))
}
```

The idea is clear: if none of the elements return value `true` on the negated predicate, then all elements satisfy the predicate. However, something is wrong with the syntax, and I can't figure out what. What is wrong in the definition of `allMatch`?

**update**
Thanks for your comments! OK, there was not much wrong with the above definition (in Swift 2.0, Xcode 7 beta), but it can be written much more concisely, see the answer below. My problem is in the following call of `allMatch`. First, this is fine:

```
var numbers = [0,2,4,6]

func isEven(n: Int) -> Bool {
    return (n % 2) == 0
}

allMatch(numbers, p: isEven)
```

But when I inline the `isEven` function, as follows:

```
allMatch(numbers, p: { n in return (n % 2) == 0 } )
```

then all I get in the side bar is the message "5 times".

Comment: Well, you have several more sets of parentheses than necessary, but I don't see any that would cause a syntax error. When you have a problem like this, you should break it down into smaller statements, using temporary variables as needed.

Comment: Also, swift 1.2 or 2.0 (xcode 6.4 or 7)?

Comment: "something is wrong with the syntax" ... "What is wrong in the definition of `allMatch`?"  ... Xcode tells you what's wrong.  100% of the time.  Stack Overflow can explain Xcode's message but you need to start with telling us what Xcode is telling you.

Comment: @nhgrif, the OP should certainly post the error message he/she's getting, but I disagree with your statement that "Xcode tells you what's wrong. 100% of the time." It tells you *something* is wrong, but often the error message you get makes no sense whatsoever. The Objective-C compiler is much, much better at giving clear error messages. I'm hoping things get better as the compiler and language evolve.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read and make an effort to understand the errors that Xcode tells you.
The compiler gives a very specific error message, and in this case (and many others) even offers to fix it for you.

[image: issue]

At some point (I thought it was 2, but this is in 1.2), Swift dropped the argument labels in standalone functions for more natural use of C functions.

As a style note, as I mentioned in a comment, you have way more parentheses than you need. You would be better off with something like this:

```
return !hasAnyMatches(list) { n in return !p(n) }
```

Comment: I might recommend writing this as `return !hasAnyMatches(list) { n in return !p(n) }`  It makes it much more readable.  Removes every set of unnecessary parenthesis.

Comment: Prior to Swift 2.0, the rules for argument labels were different for class/struct methods vs. standalone functions.  Prior to Swift 2.0, labels for arguments of standalone functions are not used unless the function explicitly provides an external name for the parameter or adds a "#" in front of the parameter name.  Swift 2.0 treats methods and standalone functions the same (first label is left off and all others are required unless you add an external label for the first argument or add "_" to suppress the label from the 2nd through last arguments.

Comment: @Kevin Many thanks for your answer! This is indeed a lot more concise. Do you have an idea what is wrong in my use of it? See my update above.